# Where does the mongoose save () method come from?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Where did this save () method come from? (usuario.save ()), since I didn't declare it anywhere.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Usuario = mongoose.model("Usuario");

store(req, res, next) {
const { nome, email, password } = req.body;
if (!nome || !email || !password)
  return res.status(422).json({ errors: "Preencha todos os campos" });

const usuario = new Usuario({
  nome,
  email
});

usuario.save().then(() => res.json({ usuario: usuario.enviarAuthJSON() }))
  .catch(next);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Usuario` is your mongodb model,
`usuario` is an instance of your  `Usuario` model called a document,
`save` is a method of your `model`

you can read this: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html

Answer (score 1):

Mongoose gives your document a set of methods to work with, you can view the full list [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html) and the part related to [save](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model-save). you can also find similar methods like `remove` in there.